# libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0:i386 not available on Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit; troubles with Adobe Air

Tags: xorg, 64-bit, gtk, shared-library, adobe-air

I've been trying to install Adobe Air on my 64 bit Ubuntu machine. The first thing I tried was to follow [this tutorial that symlinks the missing libraries](http://www.thepowerbase.com/2013/06/how-to-install-adobe-air-in-ubuntu-13-04/), but it is under the impression that HAL was still available, so I then had to follow [this guide to get HAL working](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/10/fixing-amazon-prime-streaming-drm-protected-flash-13-10). Now my issue is that when I try to run `./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin`, it tells me that it can't find `libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0` because of 13.10's folder structure (libraries aren't simply in /usr/lib anymore, they're sub-foldered by build). I then tried to make a symlink from `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0` to `/usr/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0`, but lo and behold, we need it to be a 32 bit library, says the linker:

```
/tmp/air.RYKQLa/setup: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

I can't seem to find the package `libgtk-x11` in Synaptic, and `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386` didn't get the right library. Is there a way around this or a way to get `libgtk-x11-2:i386`? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is `libgtk2.0-0:i386` installed? It is if `find -name /usr/lib 'libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0' 2>/dev/null` returns something.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried that.

Comment: I know I already installed it through apt-get, but it didn't include libgtk-x11:i386. I can't even find the package on Synaptic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said `libgtk-x11-2:i386` *is* installed (via apt, which doesn't lie, usually), you should symlink to `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0`:

```
cd /usr/lib
rm ./libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
```

Comment: Nonono, only the 32 bit version is installed. Miraculously, the 32 bit version appeared out of thin air, though. I wish that I could have found how I solved the problem.

Comment: Synaptic only deals with the package names, and doesn't pay attention to the architecture suffix (`:i386` and `:amd64`), like apt can.